# Why the state hook in react changes all elements of the object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have a list of members and each member has the same set of applications. I created 2 classes to associate each member and application and ended up with a general list of members and applications, which I wrote in the initial state.
Then, using the function, I get the ID of the member that was clicked and I want to change the state of a particular application for it from false to true. But I get a change in the state of the application from false to work for ALL members. Why is this happening and where could there be an error ???

**list members**

```
let teamMembers = [
{ 'idMember': 0, 'name': 'John Littel', 'email': 'Delores_Barrows5@hotmail.com' },
{ 'idMember': 1, 'name': 'Tom Hamill', 'email': 'Luigi0@gmail.com' },
{ 'idMember': 2, 'name': 'Ann Quitzonl', 'email': 'AnnQ@hotmail.com' },
{ 'idMember': 3, 'name': 'Frances Schuster', 'email': 'Frances.Schuster@yahoo.com' },
{ 'idMember': 4, 'name': 'Morrison Mohr', 'email': 'Rafael.Hilll64@yahoo.com' }
```

];

**list apps:**

```
let appsFromBase = ['App 0', 'App 1', 'App 2', 'App 3', 'App 4'];

class Application {
constructor(idApp, isSelected, appName) {
    this.idApp = idApp;
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
    this.appName = appName;
}

toggleSelected() { *this method changed apps from false => true*
    this.isSelected = !this.isSelected
}
```

};

```
const apps = appsFromBase.map((app, i) => new Application(i, false, app));
const membersObject = teamMembers.map((member, i) => new Member(i, member.name, member.email, apps));
```

**State:**

```
const [members, setMembers] = useState(membersObject);
```

**Handler method:**

```
    const handleChoosenApp = (app, member_i) => {
    let newMembers = { ...members };

    let _id = app.idApp;

    if (_id !== 'btn-all-app') {
        let myUpdatingMember = newMembers[member_i].apps[_id].toggleSelected()

        setMembers({ ...newMembers });
    }

}
```

*member_i, _id* - This is the member's ID and his application, which was clicked from the interface and he needs to change the value from true to false
in the console **myUpdatingMember**  I get the member and application I need, but why does the state change for everyone ???

Comment: this structure my app https://prnt.sc/16amkhj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selected state is a property of the Application, not the Member.

You create one Application array and pass it to every Member constructor.

Every Member object you create shares the same Application array.